# bind touchend event to current and future elements not responsive enough on some devices

Tags: jquery, touch-event

I want to bind an click and on touchend function to all current and future elements.

jQuery bind() works well with elements already loaded but not future/dynamic elements added after.

I have attached events using jquery .on() but touch devices don't seem to respond well.

At the moment this is what i have.

```
$(document).on('tounchend', element , function(){
    myfunction();
}).on('click', element , function(){
    myfunction();
});
```

Touch devices like iPhone/iPad/HTC one work fine but not the google nexus or htc titan...

Any ideas?

Comment: You have misspelled touchend

Comment: ah man... school boy error thanks

Comment: I have also detached the .on() separately and placed them into an if device is a touch condition.